# FadeInImage.assetNetwork requires absolute path. Relative path for placeholder is not working. (in flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, relative-path, placeholder, absolute-path

I am displaying image through `FadeInImage.assetNetwork` which requires two members : `image` and `placeholder`.

```
    ClipRRect(    //forcing image to rounded corners
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
        topRight: Radius.circular(15),
      ),
      child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
        image: imageUrl,
        placeholder: '/Users/aayush/Documents/Flutter/Apps/meals_app/assets/images/food-placeholder.png', //here full path is necessary. relative path is not working.
        // placeholder: '../../assets/images/food-placeholder.png',  //this relative path is not working.
        height: 250,
        width: double.infinity,
        fit: BoxFit.cover, //will resize and crop the image
      ),
   ),
```

### Here is my folder structure :

[image: folder structure]

Currently I am at `lib/widgets/meal_item.dart` and the placeholder image is situated at `assets/images/food-placeholder.png`.

so, my relative path will be : `../../assets/images/food-placeholder.png` .
the error message when I try to use relative path here :

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: ../../assets/images/food-placeholder.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:224
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:672
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "../../assets/images/food-placeholder.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#df521(), name: "../../assets/images/food-placeholder.png", scale: 1.0)
```

I tried it many times but it is not working only in this widget. relative path is working perfectly in other widgets.
Please give me solution for this or suggestion so that I can display placeholder image till the url image is fetched.

Here is the full screenshot :
[image: full screenshot]

Comment: Actually the problem was in relative path. The relative path should be :  `assets/images/food-placeholder.png`.
Thanks everyone for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For relative path, create path like this

```
 'assets/images/food-placeholder.png'
```

And ensure that you have added images path in assets in pubspec.yaml like this

```
assets:
- assets/images/
```

Comment: Your entry in `pubspec.yaml` won't work because you didn't specify assets folder in path.

Comment: @kishandhankecha You are right. I have updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton ! I made a mistake in writing file path. btw I already added assets in `pubspec.yaml` file. the problem was in relative path.

Comment: Hey @bilal , could you please help me if the url is broken then I also want to show the placeholder image. how can I achieve that ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @AayushShah Just like placeholder, also provide image for imageError.

Comment: Thanks @bilal ! I achieved that using `imageErrorBuilder`
sytnax : `imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>  Image.asset('assets/images/error-placeholder.png'),`

Answer (score 1):

### **You have to specify image location in `Pubspec.yaml` file.**

[image: Pubspec.yaml file]

#### Thats how you add assets to your flutter project.

- After that you can use image as below:

```dart
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
    image: imageUrl,
    placeholder: 'assets/images/food-placeholder.png',
    height: 250,
    width: double.infinity,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

***After adding image path to pub spec you have to Stop currently running session and than rebuild or re-run the App.***

- Try this commands.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! btw the problem was in relative path.